# How instruct @Mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, mockito

Writing tests of my controllers using Mockito library. When my CRUDservice saves new item, like that:

```
roomService.save(room);
```

it assign id (if id of item was null). Help me, how instruct Mock of my service to do that? Test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class RoomControllerTest {

    final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    @Mock private MockHttpSession session;

    @Mock private RoomService roomService;
    @Mock private EquipmentService equipmentService;
    @Mock private ControlService controlService;
    @InjectMocks private RoomController roomController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Room.class, new Room.RoomSerializer()).registerTypeAdapter(Room.class, new Room.RoomDeserializer()).create();

    @Before public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        //roomController = new RoomController();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(roomController).build();
    }

    @Test public void addRoomTest() throws Exception {
        Room room = new Room("Kitchen", 324);
        when(roomService.findById(1L)).thenReturn(room);
        when(roomService.save(room)).thenReturn(1L);

        Map<String, String> req = new HashMap<>();
        req.put("roomName", "Kitchen");
        req.put("squareFootage", "324");

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/room").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(gson.toJson(req)))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andReturn();

        Room retrieved = gson.fromJson(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Room.class);
        verify(roomService).save(Matchers.any(Room.class));
        assertEquals(room, retrieved);
    }
```

So how make roomController assign id to item when saves it? And how assert that after save item without id (==null) get id?

Comment: This is explained in the [documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html) - see http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer)